# Prove the exterior angle bisectors are equal

Tags: angle

Imagine a triangle with angles 132,36,12
I draw the exterior angles bisectors (132 and 12)
I want to prove that these bisectors are equal...
[Please take a look to the figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qw7m0.jpg)
I want to prove that AM'=CM
I tried to use Stewart's theorem but I couldn't prove it..

Or let me ask my question Another way:

If we have a triangle that two exterior angle bisectors of that are equal, Can we say that our triangle is isosceles?
If we can not, please give me an example...

Comment: if $AO = CO,$ then $\triangle AOC$ isoceles, in which case $\angle OAC = \angle OCA$  which it doesn't, so its not.

Comment: @DougM Thanks,I edit my question. but let me ask my question another way: " If we have a triangle that two exterior angle bisectors of that are equal, Can we say that our triangle is isosceles ? "

Comment: Now you have a problem with your angles.  If $AM'$ bisects $\angle MAC$ then $\angle M'AC = 24$ as on your first figure.  But more importantly, you have constructed a triangle with more than $180^\circ$ in the two identified angles.  (correcting for $\angle M'AC = 24$)

Comment: Anybody can help!?